# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el porcentaje de batería en COSMOS C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando RaxOS (ver en mi pregunta sobre scif:Program)
Necesito obtener el porcentaje de batería para poder poner iconos usando Segoe Fluent Icons/MDL2 (no se si puedo) o con un comando [battery --get], pero lo que quiero es obtener el porciento de bateria del ordenador, en caso de vm/torrepc que devuelva 100%, o NaN, o null;, o 0...

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: creo que si estas desarrollando en base a un S.O y buscas como obtener datos del S.O deberias enfocarte en buscar una comunidad que trate sobre el sistema operativo en cuestion. ya que no es un lenguaje de programacion no tenemos forma de decirte que estas haciendo mal o que deberias hacer . aparte de que tu pregunta busca informacion no queda claro que has intentado realmente para evitar el NaN o null.

Comment: Aparte de lo que dijo @ArcanisGK507 cuando hagas preguntas evita tener que referenciarte a preguntas previas, ya que el escenario anterior puede no ser válido para responderte correctamente y si no se puede evitar al menos dejar el link de la pregunta. Como más fácil hagas para replicarlo, más posibilidades de que te respondan correctamente.